# Retrieving ID form Database through URL

Tags: database, parameters, nestjs, uuid

I'm currently working on a little project where i need a bit of help or an advice.

Little Background Infos:
I have 3 database Tables.
**Database A** has a number of questions and all of them have a UUID which relates to Database B.
**Database B** just has a UUID which references to the Questions in Database A.
**Database C** has a one-to-one relation with Database B so it also has the UUID of Database B.

I am filling Database A and B with Postman. So I upload a CSV File which has a number of Questions. These Questions are all being saved in Database A and the upload automatically generates a Row in Database B with the UUID.

Now, when the User starts the Application, the Backend should generate a Row in Database C which references to Database B.

My Problem is, that I have no idea, how to retrieve the UUID from Database B, to save it as a reference in Database C. I have read something about doing a Response and saving the UUID from Database B in the URL so I can later use it, but I have found nothing on how to do this properly.

Can someone provide me a Link to a Documentation where I can find something on how to do it?

Thank you! :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you read the database in the other cases?

Comment: @NicoHaase I haven't triend anything so far, since I don't know How to solve this. Well in the other cases I just read and write through the Get and Post API Controllers. In this case I'm also doing it via a Post Controller but I'm not doing it via the client. I'm doing it via Postman and that's why I don't know how to return the value needed.

Comment: When I fill the database through Postman, I need to have the ID (UUID) given back to the client.